# ReferenceError: instance is not defined

Tags: javascript, odoo-9

This is my XML code. When I click a button it shows following error:

> ReferenceError: instance is not defined

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates id="template" xml:space="preserve">
  <t t-extend="ListView.buttons">
    <t t-jquery="button.o_list_button_add" t-operation="after">
      <t t-if="widget.model=='ref.reference'">
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" type="button">Enable</button>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary disable_ref" type="button">Disable</button>
      </t>
    </t>
  </t>
</templates>
```

This is in javascript what wrong in this code:

```
var ListView = require('web.ListView');

ListView.include({
    render_buttons: function() {

        // GET BUTTON REFERENCE
        this._super.apply(this, arguments)
        if (this.$buttons) {
           var btn = this.$buttons.find('.disable_ref')
        }

        // PERFORM THE ACTION
        btn.on('click', this.proxy('do_new_button'))

    },
    do_new_button: function() {

        instance.web.Model('ref.reference')
            .call('ref_dis', [[]])
    }
})
```

Comment: I see `instance` in your posted code nowhere except where you are trying to access it. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this

js

```
odoo.define('reference.js', function(require) {
    'use strict';

var ListView = require('web.ListView')
var Model = require('web.Model')

    ListView.include({
        render_buttons: function() {
            this._super.apply(this, arguments)
            if (this.$buttons) {
                this.$buttons.find('.disable_ref').on('click', this.proxy('do_new_button'))
            }
        },
        do_new_button: function () {

            var model = new Model('ref.reference')
            model.call('ref_dis', [[]]);
        }
    })
})
```

models

```
from odoo import fields, models, api

class ReferenceSource(models.Model):
    _name = "ref.reference"

    @api.model
    def ref_dis(self):
      some logic...
```